# solution of $x^x = ax^b$

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, special-functions, approximation, transcendental-equations

I am interested in the solution $x > 1$ of the transcendental equation $$x^x = ax^b$$ with $a > 1$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$. I am looking for both analytical and numerical methods, as well as approximations.

To see that the solution exists, write the equation as $\log x = A/(x-b)$ with $A = \log a$ and use the elementary [bounds of the logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bounds_of_Natural_Logarithm) to obtain the bounds $$\frac{b+1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(b-1)^2 + 4A} \leq x \leq \frac{b+1+A}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(b-1+A)^2+4 A}$$ for the solution. This is enough for general purpose numerical methods, but I would like to see if more specialised tools are available.

There is also a potential connection to the Lambert $W$-function: Write the equation as $x\log x = A + b \log x$ and set $y = x \log x$, by which $\log x = W(y)$, so that $$y = A + b \, W(y) \;.$$ This can be iterated with an initial guess based on the above bounds, but perhaps there are other useful results for the $W$-function of which I am not aware.

Comment: Have a look at my edit and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

From a formal point of view, there is probably a solution in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

This being said, consider that you look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=(x-b)\log(x)-\log(a)$$
$$f'(x)=-\frac{b}{x}+\log (x)+1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(x)=\frac{b}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{b}{W(e b)}$$ Good news : $f''(x_*) >0 \quad \forall b >0$.

Now, try a Taylor expansion to second order
$$f(x)=f(x_*)+\frac 12f''(x_*) (x-x_*)^2+O\left((x-x_*)^3\right)$$ This would give as a first estimate
$$x_0=x_*+\sqrt{-2\frac {f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$

Trying for $a=\pi$ and $b=e$, this would give $x_0=3.26318$ while the solution obtained using Newton method is $x=3.61002$. Using this estimate, the iterates of Newton method are
$$\{3.2631771,3.6338427,3.6101047,3.6100159\}$$
Trying for $a=e$ and $b=\pi$, this would give $x_0=3.51825$ while the solution obtained using Newton method is $x=3.87925$.

Try and let me know how this works for you (I have a few ideas for possible improvements).

**Edit**

From a series of numerical tests I performed, it *seems* that the left bound you proposed is good for the $x_0$ of Newton method. It can be improved at no cost using
$$\log(x) \geq 2\frac{x-1}{x+1}$$ the rhs being the simplest Padé approximant of $\log(x)$ built around $x=1$.

With $A=\log(a)$, this would give
$$x_0=\frac{1}{4} \left(A+2b+2+\sqrt{A^2+4 A (b+3)+4 (b-1)^2}\right)$$ which, for the worked examples, gives something quite close to the  geometric mean of your present lower and upper bound $(3.71264\text{ vs }3.69213)$ and $(3.97745\text{ vs }3.95909)$.

For $a=\pi$ and $b=e$, Newton iterates are
$$\{3.7126445,3.6115922,3.6100163,3.6100159\}$$
For $a=e$ and $b=\pi$, Newton iterates are
$$\{3.9774505,3.8806309,3.8792508,3.8792505\}$$

For these two cases, no overshoot during the path to solution.

Another possible approximation could be based on the fact that
$$\log(x) > \frac {e \log \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)+\left(x-\frac{e}{2}\right) \left(2+\log
   \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)\right)} {x+\frac{e}{2} }$$ as soon as $x > 1.36$.

For the worked examples, it could give $3.65464$ and $3.92416$

**Update**

Since $a >1$, as far as I can see, the solution looked for is $x>b$. So, considering
$$(x-b)\log(x)=\log(a)=A$$ approximate $\log(x)$ by its simplest Padé approximant around $x=b$ which is
$$\log(x)=\frac {2b\log(b)+ (2+\log (b))(x-b)}{x+b}$$ which leads to
$$x_0=\frac{A+4b+\sqrt{A (A+16 b)+4 b \log (b) (A+b \log (b))}}{2 (2+\log (b))}$$

For the worked examples, this gives $x_0=3.61112$ (the solution being $x=3.61002$) and $x_0=3.87962$ (the solution being $x=3.87925$).

Using $a=123456$ and $b=789$ this would give $x_0=790.75687946638$ while the solution is
$x=  790.75687946614$.

Using the same idea, we could expand $f(x)+A$ as a series around $x=b$
$$f(x)+A=(x-b)\log(b)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ b^{1-n} }{n-1}(x-b)^n$$ and use series reversion to obtain
$$x=b+t\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^p c_n u^n\right)$$ where $$L=\log(b) \qquad\qquad t=\frac{A}{L}\qquad\qquad u=-\frac{t}{b L}$$ and the $c_n$'s form the sequence
$$\left\{1,\frac{L}{2}+2,\frac{L^2}{3}+\frac{5 L}{2}+5,\frac{L^3}{4}+\frac{11
   L^2}{4}+\frac{21 L}{2}+14,\cdots\right\} $$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reference is interesting, I will have a look! Your estimate $x_0$ only seems to be a slight improvement over the lower bound in a certain range of $a$ and $b$, and requires $b > 0$. Note that the above bounds are quite good, $[3.23131, 4.21867]$ and $[3.53593, 4.43289]$ for your examples. If we are only looking to start a Newton iteration, the geometric mean of lower and upper bound does significantly better over the entire parameter range.

Comment: @student. You are welcome ! I did not disclaim in any manner what you proposed. In fact, I think that we need to choose an $x_0$ such that $f'x_0)\times f''(x_0)>0$ to avoid any overshoot of the solution (Darboux theorem). There is one in my example. I also wanted to see Lambert function here since I felt in love with it 60+ years ago.

Comment: Of course, and I was merely trying to point out (to you and in general) that it seems very difficult to do much better than using bounds for the logarithm (either those above or more advanced expressions). Iterating the $W$-function was my hope for improvement but that does not appear to go anywhere...

Comment: @student I don't think the generalized Lambert W has any help here. That aside, it wouldn't really be too helpful as far as numerical computing goes.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt. I totally agree. From a formal point of view it is nice but I have never been abale to use it for any practical application.

Comment: @student For what it's worth, the first few iterations of Newton's method are going to be fairly poor. A much cheaper alternative with initially similar speed would be to use fixed-point iteration, even if only once, on the equation $$x=b+\log_x(a)$$ If it interests you, this also bounds the solution (it sends upper bounds to lower bounds and vice versa). I also think this tends to be much better than trying to take a mean of your bounds.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks for the suggestion! In practice I have found Brent’s method to give the best convergence so far.

Comment: @student Brent's method is nice, but really not necessary for a problem like this, since an analytic derivative may be easily computed and the function is rather well-behaved (satisfying properties pointed out which guarantee convergence with Newton's method).